Eclipse RCP application not rendering menu
I inherited Eclipse RCP application with Sirius plugin embeded, app was developed around 2020-21, I'm building menus in ApplicationActionBarAdvisor and this code is executed, but when application starts menu is not rendered, there is no error/stacktrace,
I've added debug.properties to trace what is going on ui but also did not find anything interesting in additional logs, trying to debug it, but I don't know where to catch something useful. I'm also creating cool bar and this is visible, also commands like save works (using Ctrl+S), but my custom one was not executed. I feel like I make very basic mistake, because this is my first RCP app. Do I need to define menu in plugin.xml and/or Application.e4xmi or it can be done just in code?

Try starting with the -clean and -clearPersistedState options to make sure everything is rebuilt.

@greg-449 did not change anything, but thanks for good suggestion

The action bar advisor is correct for a 3.x compatability RCP (one that uses the org.eclipse.ui.xxx plug-ins) which seems to be what you have if the code is being executed.  Impossible to say exactly what is wrong with no code. You could look at the Eclipse version of the action bar advisor  WorkbenchActionBuilder to see how it does things.

@greg-449 thanks, yes this is 3.x compatability RCP (I wanted this for project explorer and other stuff), I've added code in main post, thanks for helping

I haven't looked at this stuff in a long time but it looks reasonable. Do you get the "File", "Edit" menus at all?

No menus at all, but I've already found what was wrong, thanks for your suggestions.

I found what was wrong, I was creating E4 application with E3 compatibility mode using tutorial found on Internet, from this tutorial I've added reference to Application.e4xmi in plugin.xml this was overriding/conflicting code created by me, so the effect was not menu at all. Removing this reference helped also with custom command. I'm kind of new with this RCP development and still learning, any one could recommend tutorial/book?

The tutorials on vogella.com are generally reliable such as this one. Lars is one of the Eclipse contributors.

For RCP development see the tutorials at vogella.com and for e4 there is a nice tutorial by Jonas Helming which I can recommend.
